# Move qemu image to real device

Tags: mips, embedded-linux, qemu

I have a development board with a mips processor. It is possible to create a Linux qemu image, install some package in it, add some binaries, and deploy it as an install image to the board? The point here is to keep all the packages and binaries, not just the kernel.

If so, after putting it on the board, will the OS detect the interfaces, USB, serial, SATA, etc?

Comment: Do you mean copy the contents of the qemu image to the actual board?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for. For exemple, I have a qemu instance, add some packages with apt-get install and after that put it on a board to deploy in production. This way I want to avoid building all the dependencies along with the business logic that will run on the board and have them preinstaled.

Comment: The final use case is to put that image on a stick, ship it to final customer so he could flash tee board and have it up and running.

Comment: if that is you end goal you can achive this by doing the necessary steps and `chroot` to your basic root folder, install all the packages and then pack that new rootfs